# TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use this line code to wait until product_id appear, My code works well for about 30 minutes

```
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, product_id)))
```

And then, I get an error

```
TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I tried to change WebDriverWait to 100, but I still can't solve them. I want to understand why to appear this error and any solution for this case. Thanks so much !!!

This is my solution, but I want to know the cause of this error and looking for a better solution

```
  while True:
    driver.get(URL)
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, product_id)))
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide HTML example? Without HTML example it's nearly impossible to debug for you. Code & HTML example will be helpful.

My guess is that your website uses dynamic id locators, or using iframe, or in your script, selenium is active on other tab/window/iframe/content. This is assuming your `product_id` is correct.

---

Update with the example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PRODUCT_ID = 'productTitle'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08BB9RWXD")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, PRODUCT_ID)))
    print(element.text)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Cannot find product title.")

driver.quit()
```

I don't have any problem using above code. You can extend it by youself :).

One thing that you need to note is that you DO NOT use `while` & `break`. `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` already does the loop to find your element for 10 seconds. In this 10 seconds, if it finds your element, it will stop finding (`break`). You don't need to do the `while` loop yourself.

Comment: This is the [link](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08BB9RWXD) I want to scrap, I want to find  "productTitle" and  I were set `product_id = "productTitle"`. Thank you, sorry for bad English !

Comment: I updated the answer for an example. It's working fine from my example and no exception that i can observe. Don't worry about your English, it's fine, and I also come from your country :).

Comment: I know your thinks, but here [link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) is the way which `webdriverwait` work. You can read clearly more again :D. I want to use loop until to find the "productTitle"

Comment: You can do that, but it's bad practice. Does my example help your question? Is there any problem you have?

Comment: Your code will stop if TimeoutException raise, I need to loop to find "productTitle" :D.